# Running selenium script in IE throws error "Only local connections are allowed."

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-iedriver

I've tried many things but still facing the same error. Can someone please help to suggest a solution?

> **Issue:** When running selenium script in IE, I'm getting the following error. 
>   **Setting:** I'm using IE 11 and selenium 2.53.0

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 10402
Only local connections are allowed
```

**Things I have tried so far:**

> 1. Changed IE Security setting such that all different zones are set to have Security Level = High
> 2. Unchecked 'Enable Protected Mode' for all zones
> 3. I tried both 32 bits and 64 bits of IEDriverServer.exe
> 4. I tried to add the following codes after setting system property for the driver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

---

**Update**

I updated selenium driver to 3.0.1 and changed IEDriver to 32 bits and getting following error

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.53.1.0
Listening on port 5420
Only local connections are allowed
Sep 26, 2017 12:03:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Sep 26, 2017 12:03:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Sep 26, 2017 12:03:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.testng.internal.TestResult.toString(TestResult.java:245)
    at org.testng.internal.TestResult.toString(TestResult.java:226)
```

---

**Resolution**
For anyone who might be interested, I have resolved my issue based on the two posts below.

Basically
1) Need to modify registry setting
2) Extend browser capability to ignore zone setting and protected mode setting

[IELaunchURL issue with Selenium IE Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452091/ielaunchurl-issue-with-selenium-ie-driver)

[In IE: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451412/in-ie-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-this-usually-means-that-a-call-to)

Comment: use latest selenium version